Maven multimodule not building submodule directly
I have a maven multimodule with the given structure:
root
--- pom.xml
------ apps
--------- serviceA
--------- serviceB
------ libs
--------- libraryA
--------- libraryB
------------ libraryBa
------------ libraryBb

in the apps pom.xml, I have a dependencyManagement section that includes libraryB as <type>pom</type> and <scope>import</scope>.
What works: mvn clean package -pl :serviceX -am from the root directory.
What I want to work but doesn't work: mvn clean package -am from the service directory. It is unable to locate libraryB for some reason.
Why isn't maven able to build libraryB?

Show the actual pom

Does each module have its own pom? You need to build the whole project, not just one module. Only then does maven build them in the required order, otherwise you need to mvn install your libraries so they are in your local maven repo and can be found without rebuilding them.

@f1sh Each module has its own pom.xml, of course.
I expected the build to work from any service directory.
